# Сравнение в cmp и вызов call

Tags: ассемблер

Мне нужно сравнить какое-то число и например если равно то задействовать call чтоб кое сделать потом вернутся обратно.
Я не знаю как сделать чтоб call сработал если условие выполнилось и потом возвратилось.

Comment: `cmp // jnz x // call // x:`

Comment: @Mike трудно понять вторую половину

Comment: какую вторую половину ? Проверяем условие, если "НЕ равно", то обходим инструкцию call переходя к строке после нее, которую помечаем меткой `x:`. Если же условие будет равно то произойдет сначала call, а после возврата из функции мы окажемся в строке `x:`

Comment: @Mike  спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Mike, ответы - в ответы

Comment: @ Qwertiy♦ он итак в теме ответ